# Nothing appears when I try to read a local excel file in a recyclerview. What can resolve this problem?

Tags: java, android, excel, android-recyclerview, local-files

I'm a young French developer who hasn't really learned coding but I'm doing pretty well anyway.

The problem is that I am developing an application that can read (and write) data to an Excel spreadsheet but nothing is showing.

After several searches, I found 2 tutorials from which I was inspired to write my code but the problem is that my application does not display anything. It is supposed to display a list (in a recyclerview) of the various data already present on the excel file.
The excel file is in xls but nothing is displayed, would you know what to do?

Tutorial link (view an Excel file online in recyclview): [Here] [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxdVo4RH3nE)

Link to the excel file reading tutorial: [Here] [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iTRAwCazw8)

I don't want an online file, is this possible?
if possible, how? Thank you in advance.

My code :

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Adapter adapter;

List<String> name= new ArrayList<>(), weight= new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startXLFilereading();

    //initialisation du recyclerView (Liste des moules)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.Listxxxxx);
    adapter = new Adapter(this, name, weight);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void startXLFilereading(){
    //Lecture du fichier exel (.xls)
    try {
        AssetManager am = getAssets();
        InputStream is = am.open("ID_xxxxx.xls");
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
        Sheet s = workbook.getSheet(0);
        int r = s.getRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++){

            Cell[] row = s.getRow(i);
            name.add(row[0].getContents());
            weight.add(row[1].getContents());
        }

    } catch (Exception e){

    }
}

}
```

Adapter.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<String> name, weight;

public Adapter(Context context, List<String> name, List<String> weight) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_xxxx_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.TVname.setText(name.get(position));

    if (weight.get(position) == null) {
        holder.TVweight.setText("Poid non renseigné");
    } else {
        holder.TVweight.setText(weight.get(position) + " tonnes");
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return name.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView TVname, TVweight;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        TVname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.SNom);
        TVweight = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Single_Weight);

    }
}
}
```

single_xxxx_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="#FFF7D0">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/SNom"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:text="Nom"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Single_Weight"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Single_Weight"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Poid"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SNom" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/Listxxxxx"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please also show the xml file containing the recycler view and the xml file with the list entry layout.

Comment: @TarikWeiss I added that

Comment: Did you try debugging the arrays where the reader reads into? Possibly they're empty.

Comment: I don't really understand. I've already try to debug parts of my code but what part exactly are you talking about ?

Comment: When you finished your xlFileReading thingy are the lists empty after that or not? You may use `Log.d("YourTag", name.size() + " entries in name.");` for this purpose.

Comment: It tells me that is empty. "0 entries in name."

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. My xls file was not really in .xls format but had this name: MyFile.xls.xlxs

I just recreated my file in .xls format and it's good. Thanks anyway to TarikWeiss